# JavaScript variable empty after call of getJSON()

Tags: javascript, getjson

I'm having this issue with importing data from a JSON file. I use the `.getJSON` function to get the data which means to work according to the console log, but once I move out of the getJSON sub function the array in data2 disappears. I've narrowed it down to this section here:

```
function prepData() {
    data2 = [];

    $.getJSON('http://localhost/data').done(function(json) {
        data2 =json;
        console.log(data2);
    });

    console.log(data2);
    SelectedData = data2;
    return SelectedData;
};
```

What might the issue be here?

Comment: Async code (like your call to getJSON) will not cause your code to halt execution until it completes. This is why it is async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function:

```
function(json) {
    data2 = json;
}
```

is executed *after*

```
console.log(data2);
SelectedData = data2;
```

`data2` is not defined yet at that point.

---

```
(1) function prepData(){
(2)    data2 = []; 

(3)    $.getJSON('http://localhost/data').done(function(json) {
(4)        data2 =json;
(5)        console.log(data2);
       });

(6)    console.log(data2);
(7)    SelectedData= data2;
(8)    return SelectedData;
   };
```

Execution order:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 4 -> 5
```

---

Common practice - Return promise instead of data:

```
function prepData(){
    return $.getJSON('http://localhost/data');
}

// more code here

prepData().done(function(json){
    console.log(json);
});
```

Take a look at these more detailed demos.
jQuery on ES5: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/xtmy6po0/

```
function timeout(n){
    // create promise
    var defer = $.Deferred();

    // resolve after n milliseconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        defer.resolve(n);
    }, n);

    // return new promise that apply custom text
    return defer.then(function(v){
        return "Resolved after " + (v/1000) + " seconds";
    });
}

timeout(3000).then(function(message){
    // will be executed after 3 seconds
    alert(message);
});
```

Equivalent ES7: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/8kLknbne/

```
async function timeout(n){
    // create timer
    let timer = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(n), n));
    // return message
    return "Resolved after " + (await timer()/1000) + " seconds";
}

// call
timeout(3000).then(alert);
```

Comment: Well thats stupid. Is there any way to change get Json to run in the order written down?

Comment: @Exostrike That's just how promises are designed to work. Remember you only have one single thread and you can't block a thread since it would also block all UI updates. Instead of returning the data, return the promise (or a deffered object in jQuery) instead.

Comment: @Exostrike Take a look at this demo if you need more help on handling asynchronous calls: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/xtmy6po0/

Comment: @Exostrike Here's a piece of equivalent code in the newest ES7 instead of using jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/8kLknbne/

Answer (score 0):

The .done is an event so it will happen few milliseconds or seconds later than the other script, it only occurs when the request to http://localhost/data is completed

this will run first:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/data');
console.log(data2);
SelectedData= data2;
return SelectedData;
```

few seconds later .done event will be fired 
then this will run

```
data2 =json;
console.log(data2);
```

my suggestion is in the .done function call another function that process the answer, instead of waiting for return value which will return as undefined in your code

Answer (score -2):

$.getJSON is asynchronous so it will executed parallel to your next console statement.

Comment: Nope. JavaScript is single threaded, that means (4) and (5) (refer to my answer) must execute after the function returned.

Comment: It won't be executed in parallel. It will be executed at some point after the current code execution finished. (The top of the execution stack is reached on no further code to execute exists).

Comment: @t.niese thanks for clarity. That's what i mean to say.